# how to add the same templates with different event

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have one template(slider) passed two times. Now I need to add an event(slide) only to the first "slider" template. It's possible to do this? How to pass this event props? Is anybody can show me on some simple event example?

```
Parent component


<template>
 <div>
   <Heading 
     color="#215398"      
     font_color="#ffffff"
    />
   <Slider // --> only here I would like to have a slider   
     color="#215398"
     img="images/wp_logo.png"
     prev="block"
     next="block"
   />
   <Slider 
     color="#F5F5F5"
     img="images/shape.png"
     prev="none"
     next="none"
   />
  </div>
</template>
```

.

```
Slider component


.slider
.container.center(
    :style="{backgroundColor: color}"
    )
    .main_box.center
        .slider_boxs                
            .prev
                img(src="images/arrow_left.png" 
                :style="{display: prev}"
                )
            .slider_box(v-for="box in data")
                .slider_box__title
                    h3 {{box.title}}
                .slider_box__text
                    p {{box.text}}
                .slider_box__img
                    img(:src="src")
            .next
                img(
                    src="images/arrow_right.png" 
                    :style="{display: next}"
                )
```

Comment: unclear description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an event like below

```
<Slider @slide="onSlideEvent"
 color="#215398"
 img="images/wp_logo.png"
 prev="block"
 next="block"
/>

and in methods

methods: {
  onSlideEvent (someData) {
    // it will be triggered when you use this.$emit('slide', somedata) from the Slide component
  
  } 
}
```

It the slide component, you don't need to define this in the props, just use

```
this.$emit('slide', somedata)
```

and it will trigger the parent event which you have passed

and if you don't pass this event to the second slider, you can put some conditions inside Slider component to check if the event has passed.